# Problem with nested associations in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having a problem with some associations in Rails3.

I have the following associations

```
InformationCategory :has_many => Informations :has_many => InformationValues
```

I'm able to succesfully do the following:

```
Information.first.information_values
=> [#InformationValue..]
```

I'm also able to do the following:

```
InformationCategory.first.informations
=> [#Information...]
```

However, for some reason, this fails:

```
InformationCategory.first.informations.first.information_values
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `information_values' for #<Information:0x000001053321c8>
```

Why can't I use 'nested associations' in Rails? The error message clearly states that `InformationCategory.first.informations.first` returns an instance of `Information`

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By the way, if I inspect the Information-object in the case where it fails, it shows that none of the 'magic' association methods are added to the object.

Comment: Could you please post the code from your models?

Answer (score 0):

You don't define all the nested descendants on outermost model: each model defines what it "directly" has_many of, or the model it belongs_to. Because your question is wrong, I can only guess without seeing more specifically how your models are supposed to be related.

This might be a start:

```
class InformationCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :informations
end

class Information < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :information_category
  has_many :information_values
end

class InformationValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :information
end
```

However, you might be trying to do a `has_many :through`, but I can't tell from your question.